# Mapping role-names to from roles

Tags: ldap, tomcat7, jndi, web.xml, security-constraint

I configured a LDAP realm for tomcat 7. It searches for someone in the group users, once found will authenticate them and allow them to access the application.

This is my realm:

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm"
          connectionURL="ldap://adldap.mycompany.com:3268"
          userSearch="(sAMAccountName={0})"
          userSubtree="true"
          userBase="DC=mycompany,DC=com"
          roleSubtree="true"
          roleName="CN"
          userRoleName="memberOf"/>
```

It finds the user then searches for the corresponding role-names. This is my security constraints with roles in the web.xml.

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>user</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>user</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>PUT</http-method>
        <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
        <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
        <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
        <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description>users</description>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <role-name>user</role-name>
</security-role>
```

But the user will have roles that look like `CN=Domain Users,CN=Users,DC=mycompany,DC=com`. So my question is, is there a way I can map that role to the role-name of user? Otherwise I need to define my security constraints as such:

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>user</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>user</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>PUT</http-method>
        <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
        <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
        <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
        <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description>users</description>
        <role-name>CN=Domain Users,CN=Users,DC=mycompany,DC=com</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <role-name>CN=Domain Users,CN=Users,DC=mycompany,DC=com</role-name>
</security-role>
```

Answer (score 0):

*map that role to the role-name of user?*

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm"
   connectionURL="ldap://adldap.mycompany.com:3268"
   userSearch="(sAMAccountName={0})"
   userSubtree="true"
   userBase="DC=mycompany,DC=com"
   roleSubtree="true"
   roleName="CN"
   userRoleName="sAMAccountName"/>
```

This should (I could not test it) pull the attribute (sAMAccountName) from the user entry that is authenticated.

Comment: Thank you for the help but, I meant map the role name "CN=Domain Users,CN=Users,DC=mycompany,DC=com" to be equal "user" instead of having to type out the entire rolename above. Hope this helps clearify. Like I was saying I was just wondering if it was at all possible.

Comment: AFIK, no. But since.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

```
<security-role-ref>
<role-name>CN=Domain Users,CN=Users,DC=mycompany,DC=com</role-name>
<role-link>user</role-link>
</security-role-ref>
```

Comment: That's what I ended up doing but I was looking for a simpler way than to list out the entire role name.